# Any ideas why I am getting "Could not a connection to sql server" error?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have had the below error messages before and was able to resolve them by configuring sql server using sql server surface area configuration option to allow for remote accessing.

I have also checked firewall on the database server and it was turned off.

Yet, this is the first time I am setting php to connect to sql server remotely.

When I attempted to test the connection, I got the following:

```
Unable to connect.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )
```

This sql server is our production DB and is configured to allow for remote accessing.

All of our apps are able to connect to this sql server from various remote servers with the exception of this server which hosts our PHP.

I have checked the resources the on this forum and other places and each is suggesting to try the same things I have tried already.

I am not sure if the way I set up the php connection string is the problem.

Below is a sampling of it.

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.44.10,1433";
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "myuser", "PWD" => "myPass", "Database"=>"Kittens");
/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}
?>
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Please say that this isn't your real password and your real IP address !!

Comment: No, of course not. They don't even look real especially the username and password pair.

Comment: Two big pieces of information right in the error message. "Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections." Can you ping that IP from where your php is running? And does the sql server allow remote connections?

Comment: Also check if the right syntax to pass aN ip->port is with a comma because I think that it should be `192.168.44.10:1433` `:` instead of a `,`

Comment: @JorgeCampos, you are right about the aN ip->port.

I have always used : (colon) instead of , (comma) but I read where someone says if you are using php to connect to sql server using windows, then instead of colon, use comma. Not sure how true that is but none of those instances worked.

Sean, as indicated in my original post, sql server is set up to allow remote connections